# Как в Objective-C написать условия для кнопки перехода из одной сцены к другой

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationcontroller

При использовании `Navigation Controller` соединил две `View Controller` через кнопку "Войти" по принципу Show (Push).

При нажатии срабатывает переход, это работает, но нужен переход только при выполнении условия. Для понимания, например, только если авторизация прошла успешно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать это через `Storyboard ID`, если он прописан то можно составить условие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if (условие) {
     //Контроллер в которому нужно перейти.
     CategoryController * detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoryController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: А где прописывается это условие?
Попытался написать в  ViewController.m в действии этой кнопки, но там Storyboard ID второго экрана не знает, в итоге не могу объявить *detail

Comment: `Storyboard ID` прописывается в `main.storyboard` того контроллера куда тебе надо переходить, во `ViewController` делаешь импорт того контроллера куда надо переходить например `#import "CategoryController.h"`